# Ruling on finding entertainment in a fictional setting of supernatural elements

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, kufr

What is the ruling on the one who finds entertainment in TV shows or comic books that depict humans with abnormal abilities like resurrecting the dead? For example, one sees this action and says to themselves "this is pretty cool, I wish Allah (swt) permitted me with such an ability that befits me as a human" and they say this in a fictional or fantastical way? Would such type of entertainment or fantasy be considered an act of kufr al akbar, let alone sinful? How would this apply to other fantasies as well like wishing to fly or so and so. Likewise, I understand such type of thinking may not be useful or time well spent, but it greatly troubles me that it could be considered something to be an act of kufr al akbar.

Answer (score 0):

السلام عليكم ورحمة الله وبركاته
بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم

Read stories that contain the ability to fly or shoot water is permissible

The Forbidden are those abilities that God mentioned are the ones that do it or give it to someone to uses it, like the angel of death.

It is forbidden to read stories in which the dead are revived.

Drawing does not make what is forbidden permissible. This rule must be understood.

Comment: Is it kufr al akbar to find entertainment in these stories? Likewise, is it kufr al akbar to wish Allah gave you those abilities in a human like way?

Comment: It's not kufr al akbar In both of them

Comment: Okay, thank you!